# Unable to take raw inputs in python when I use input statement one after the other

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error

I'm trying to use a second input statement, right after the first, for example:

```
a = int(input())
c = int(input())
print(a+c)
```

but I get an error right after I enter the second value.

while online compilers are giving me the expected output, my IDE gives this error as soon as I enter my second value :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Projects\PythonProjects\HelloWorld\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    c = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: Please [edit] to provide details on which IDE you are using, how you are running the code using that IDE, and how you are entering the inputs. I'm guessing either you might be pressing Enter too many times or the IDE assumes there's only 1 input.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the second input value is an empty string and you cannot convert an empty string to an `int`

Try adding some text to your input function so you have a clear signal when you should be pressing `enter`.  Also make sure that you are only entering numeric values for your input otherwise it will fail to cast the value to an `int`

For example:

```
a = int(input("Enter first value: "))
c = int(input("Enter second value: "))
print(a+c)
```